# Checkbox data not coming through in django

Tags: python, django

I have a html template with multiple checkboxes, when i run request.POST.getlist(), I get an empty list back regardless of what checkboxes are selected.

view class:
class AddNewDevice(TemplateView):

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    context['devices'] = get_devices(request.user)
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post_data = request.POST
    print(request.POST.getlist('devices_selected'))
    save_data(request.POST.getlist('devices_selected')) 
    return redirect('/dashboard.html')
```

html form:

```
 <form method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
      devices</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Serie Nummer</th>
              <th>Gebouw</th>
              <th>Locatie</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for device in devices %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{obj.serial_number}}" name="devices_selected">
              </td>
              <td>{{device.serial_number}}</td>
              <td>{{device.device_building}}</td>
              <td>{{device.device_location}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Geupdate om 12:00 uur</div>
  </div>

   <br>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Toevoegen</button>

   <br>
  </form>
```

As i stated earlier request.POST.getlist('devices_selected') returns an empty list, regardless of what is selected. I want a list with all the values (obj.serial_number) from the selected checkboxes.

Comment: My first guess would be to do `getlist('devices_selected[]')`. However, you could also just print out request.POST to see what's actually coming into your POST-dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything called `obj` in your template context, so the value attribute is empty. The item in each loop is `device`.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ device.serial_number }}" name="devices_selected">
```